Karate uses default timeouts when a reusable feature is used
For some time now, we have had the problem that we sometimes get read timeouts after 5000ms, even though 30000ms are configured globally in karate-config.js.
We have now realised that we only get the timeouts for feature files that are called from another feature. For example
* def signIn = call read('classpath:my-signin.feature') { username: 'john', password: 'secret' }

Our assumption is that the globally configured timeouts are overwritten with the default timeouts as soon as another feature is called with call read.
You could configure the timeouts again in every scenario that is reused. But this is quite error-prone and tedious.
Feature: here are the contents of 'my-signin.feature'

Scenario:
* configure readTimeout = 10000
  Given url loginUrlBase
  And request { userId: '#(username)', userPass: '#(password)' }
  When method post
  Then status 200
  And def authToken = response

  # second HTTP call, to get a list of 'projects'
  Given path 'users', authToken.userId, 'projects'
  When method get
  Then status 200
  # logic to 'choose' first project
  And set authToken.projectId = response.projects[0].projectId;

Can anyone tell me if our guess is correct or if we are doing something wrong?

you may be right that there is a bug that karate resets the timeout in a "call". feel free to open an issue. I also urge you to help (if possible) by debugging and seeing where it might be happening in the code, and PR would be awesome
